# Sidebar via Controller - Laravel 5.1 + AdminLTE 2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Boa tarde! Estou com o seguinte problema aqui...
Na minha `view` modelo `app.blade.php` tenho a linha `@include('partials.sidebar')` que inclui minha sidebar, ok. A questão é que tenho 2 sidebar diferentes, uma para cada "tipo de cadastro", então queria fazer esse include dinamicamente pelo meu controller, seria possível?

Gostaria de passar +/- isso:

```
return view('inicio')->with(['sidebar' => 'partials.sidebarAdmin']);
```

ou

```
return view('inicio')->with(['sidebar' => 'partials.sidebarUser']);
```

de acordo com o que foi definido no controller.

mas se eu coloco `@include($sidebar)` na minha view `app.blade.php`, retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Undefined variable: sidebar (View: D:\App\resources\views\app.blade.php)
```

Como eu poderia passar esse dado para a view?

Obs: Sim, minha view "inicio" está com o `@extends('app')` funcionando corretamente.

Comment: O erro era outro, eu estava direcionando a view errada, e não a que eu estava testando. Desculpe e obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que eu achei foi trabalhar via `GET`, passando os parâmetros *admin* e outro *usuário*.

### Criando uma Rota

A primeira coisa que eu fiz foi criar uma *rota* para o *template*, que recebe um parâmetro `GET` contendo o usuário atual, depois eu direciono a lógica para um *controller* chamado **tratandoOSideBarViaGET.php**, que por sua vez chama o método *page*:

```
<?php
Route::get('suaURLPreferida/{whichUser}', 'tratandoOSideBarViaGET@page');
```

### Gerando o Controller

Feito isso eu gero um *controller* usando o comando `php artisan make:controller tratandoOSideBarViaGET` que aparecerá no diretório `App\Http\Controllers\`.

Agora que vem a parte divertida :D

No *controller* eu defino aquele método *page* que recebe um parâmetro **whichUser** responsável por retornar o usuário atual. Então dentro do método eu aponto para *views* e busco pelo template **inicio.blade.php**, nele eu defino um parâmetro `$user`, responsável por saber se estamos fazendo uma chamada do *Admin* ou do *Usuário*:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class tratandoOSideBarViaGET extends Controller
{
    public function page($whichUser)
    {
        return view('inicio')->with('user', $whichUser);
    }
}
```

### Template

Finalmente no *template* eu crio uma condição, se `$user` for *admin* então `@include('sidebarAdmin')`, ou se `$user` for *usuario* então `@include('sidebarUser')`, se ambas retornarem `false` não mostra nada:

```
@if ($user == 'admin')
    @include('sidebarAdmin')
@elseif ($user == 'usuario')
    @include('sidebarUser')
@endif
```

### Considerações finais

Perceba que esta não é única maneira de se fazer isto, porém seria uma boa prática você seguir com ela. Entenda você poderia muito bem fazer assim:

```
<?php
Route::get('suaURLPreferida/{whichUser}', function ($whichUser) {
    return view('inicio')->with('user', $whichUser);
});
```

Eu não recomendo isto, porque você está misturando as funções do MVC, não é função de uma *rota* adicionar um parâmetro a uma *view*, isto cabe ao *controller* por isso separei as responsabilidades. Sinta-se a vontade de escolher a melhor solução, apenas queria deixar claro o meu ponto de vista.

Comment: Muito bom @joão! Goatei muito dessa solução, me deu até uma outra ideia rs. Mas me diz uma coisa, eu realmente não queria deixar um if da view definir isso, pode ser bobeira minha, mas não acho muito seguro. Será que n teria uma maneira de deixar isso no controller ou na middleware?

Comment: @RaylanSoares fico feliz por ter gostado da minha solução. Bom como eu disse anteriormente, é uma boa prática você separar seu código em  responsabilidades. Agora você querer usar este mesmo Controller ou uma Middleware para manipular HTML, vai contra este princípio entende?

Comment: @RaylanSoares Não há problema algum de você usar o "IF" nas Views. O "IF" é uma regra sintática do Blade (Template Engine), que propõe uma maneira alternativa de integrarmos HTML com PHP, deixando-os assim mais "clean". Tanto que se for reparar, a extensão dos arquivos são "blade.PHP" ou seja, o arquivo na realidade é PHP e todos nós estamos cientes de que PHP é seguro (ou quase :D).

Comment: @RaylanSoares A função do BLADE na realidade é fazer um PARSE dessa "sintaxe alternativa" para o PHP tradicional que conhecemos. E outra, você acha que o Taylor Otwell (criador do Laravel) permitiria a documentação de algo, que ele não consideraria seguro? Acho que não né? hahaha

Comment: @RaylanSoares Enfim acho que já escrevi bastante kkkkk Agora porque não da uma olhada no [repositório](https://github.com/joaosvieira/stackoverflow) que eu criei apenas para respostas aqui do **Stack Overflow**? A sua pergunta é a primeira de muitas hahaha

Comment: kkk escreveu bastante sim, mas tudo foi de extrema ajuda, muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos @João Paulo Vieira da Silva

Answer (score 2):

Sua sintaxe esta incorreta.

O correto seria...

```
return view('inicio')->with('sidebar' => 'partials.sidebarAdmin');
return view('inicio')->with('sidebar' => 'partials.sidebarUser');
```

Ou até

```
$sidebar = 'partials.sidebarUser';
return view('inicio', compact('sidebar'));
```

Ou ainda...

```
return view('inicio', ['sidebar' => 'partials.sidebarUser']);
```

---

Quanto a condição para apresentar sidebars diferentes, você pode fazer tanto no controller, quanto na view ou até usando **view composers**.

Comment: então, eu usei a terceira opção, pois eu passo uma mensagem tambem, mas nao funcionou, continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: return view('inicio', ['message' => 'sucesso', 'sidebar' => 'partials.sidebar']);

Comment: O erro era outro, eu estava direcionando a view errada, e não a que eu estava testando. Desculpe e obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: mas de qualquer forma a sintaxe estava errada mesmo.

Comment: @RaylanSoares tranquilo meu amigo.